# Filtering themes based on words in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, filtering

I am trying to assign specific filters/themes in the C:C column to each row based on words in the A:A column.

E.g. content in the A column "What do the trade signals look like?"
I want to assign that specific row by the name "trade signals" in the C column.

It does not filter correctly. It pastes "Not Captured" in all the C-cells of all rows.

```vb
Sub EmailThemes()
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim InsertRng As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Range("C8:C10000").Clear

Set SearchRange = Worksheets("Data").Range("A7:A1500")
Set InsertRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("C7:C1500")

For Each Cell In SearchRange
    If Cell.Value Like "*Chart*" = True Then
        InsertRng.Value = "Charts"
        
    ElseIf Cell.Value Like "*Investor*" = True Then
        InsertRng.Value = "Investor"
        
    ElseIf Cell.Value Like "*Trade Signals*" = True Then
        InsertRng.Value = "Trade Signals"
    
    ElseIf Cell.Value Like "*Account*" = True Then
        InsertRng.Value = "Account"
    
    ElseIf Cell.Value Like "*Watchlist*" & "*Trade*" & "*Order*" = True Then
        InsertRng.Value = "Trading"
    
    Else
        InsertRng.Value = "Not Captured"
    
    End If
    
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: please also add some sample input with desired output to help us better understand your problem

Comment: E.g. I have a row with the following content:
A Column - Subject: FW: New columns added to the Trade blotter
|
B Column - Date: 3/11/2020
|
C Column - Theme: Not Captured
|
Here the macro should pick up that the Subject contains the word "Trade" and assign Theme "Trading" instead of theme "Not Captured".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate through `SearchRng`, however you don't update the corresponding cell in `InsertRng`, but each step you overwrite the whole `InsertRng`.

As at the end you'll always have empty cells which don't match any conditions you'll just get "Not captured" everywhere.

It's always a good idea to debug your code so you'll see what happens after running each line of code.

You can do something like:

`Intersect(Cell.EntireRow,InsertRng).Value = "..."`